# How to read array from QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt

I want to write data stored in a vector (holding structs) to a file and also read data from that file. I try to do this with QDataStream and overloading the ">>" and "<<" operators. Everything worked until I added a char array to the struct. 
Something must be wrong in the way I try to read the string from the QDataStream. I tried different ways to read the string but I always get an error.

Here are the structs:

```
typedef struct
{
   char data[cNetworkMessageLengthMax + 1];   //cNetworkMessageLengthMax=19
} __attribute__((packed)) networkMessageBody_t;


typedef struct 
{
    baseStation_daytime_t   timestamp;
    uint32_t                blueId;
    networkMessageBody_t    message;
} __attribute__((packed)) baseStation_mailbox_t;
```

and the operators:

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const std::vector<baseStation_mailbox_t> &data)
{
    for(uint8_t i=0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        out << data[i].timestamp.time.hour;
        out << data[i].timestamp.time.minute;
        out << data[i].timestamp.time.second;
        out << data[i].timestamp.time.thousandth;
        out << data[i].timestamp.date.day;
        out << data[i].timestamp.date.month;
        out << data[i].timestamp.date.year;

        out << data[i].blueId;

        out << data[i].message.data;
    }
    return out;
}

QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, std::vector<baseStation_mailbox_t> &data)
{
    uint16_t tmp16;
    uint32_t tmp32;
    char tmpChar[20];

    uint8_t i = 0;
    while(in.atEnd() == false)
    {
        data.emplace_back();

        in >> data[i].timestamp.time.hour;
        in >> data[i].timestamp.time.minute;
        in >> data[i].timestamp.time.second;
        in >> tmp16;
        data[i].timestamp.time.thousandth = tmp16;
        in >> data[i].timestamp.date.day;
        in >> data[i].timestamp.date.month;
        in >> tmp16;
        data[i].timestamp.date.year = tmp16;

        in >> tmp32;
        data[i].blueId = tmp32;

        in >> tmpChar;                 //HERE I get errors
        data[i].message.data = tmpChar;

        i++;
    }

    return in;
    }
```

Comment: Why not `QString`?

Comment: I cant change the char array data in networkMessageBody_t. Other than that I am not opposed to QString, but if I knew how to use it in this case I wouldnt be here ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace:

- `out << data[i].message.data;` with `out << QByteArray::fromRawData(data[i].message.data,std::extent<decltyple(data[i].message.data)>::value);`
- `char tmpChar[20];` with `QByteArray tmpChar;`
- `data[i].message.data = tmpChar;` with `std::copy(tmpChar.constBegin(),tempChar.constEnd(),data[i].message.data);`

Comment: That works, thank you! But even after looking at the manpage I don't really understand how that part is returning the size of the data array: `std::extent<decltyple(data[i].message.data)>::value`
Could you elaborate what `extent` and value is `doing` here?

Comment: From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent:

template< class T, unsigned N = 0>
struct extent;
  

If T is an array type, provides the member constant value equal to the number of elements along the Nth dimension of the array

You can replace it with `20` but this way if you change the size of data the size in extent is adjusted automatically